# How can I convert Special Format String to Text?

Tags: string, hex

How can I convert the string `00 00 EF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00` to text?

I googled and found a online tool which can convert binary to text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This values are in HEX - [This tool](http://home2.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/)
does hex as well, you can always transalte HEX to decimal and then take their ASCII value...

Comment: notice it works for values below 128 (decimal) and it's for ASCII based text.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [tool](http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-encoder-tool/) few years ago that can convert/encode strings. Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here the text you've supplied is "as is", with spaces separating the hex digit pairs.

You can convert each hex value with, e.g.:

```
byte.Parse("EF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
```

So you can convert the whole to a byte array:

```
var byteArray = "0A 0A 0A".Split(' ').Select(s => byte.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)).ToArray();
```

However, you don't specify what character encoding your hex stream represents.  Once you've got your byte array, you'll need to convert it as necessary.

Comment: DIY tutorial for me. Thank you. :-)